# how to popup several parts of text in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am having this html structure and i want the content inside class"CodeBlock" to open in a new window:

```
<a href="javascript:popup();">Open</a>
<div class="CodeBlock">
line 1<br />
line 2<br />
line 3
</div>
<br /><br />
<a href="javascript:popup();">Open</a>
<div class="CodeBlock">
line 4<br />
line 5<br />
line 6
</div>
```

I am trying to catch each class with the following javascript:

```
function popup()
{
var generator=window.open('','name','height=400,width=500');

generator.document.write('<html><head><title>Popup</title>');
generator.document.write($(".CodeBlock").html());
generator.document.write('</body></html>');
generator.document.close();
}
```

This opens the first Codeblock and i am trying now to open the second Codeblock with the second anchor:

```
generator.document.write($.next(".CodeBlock").html());
```

But the .next() seems not to work; both the popups are empty.

What i am doing wrong and how can i make this work properly?

http://jsfiddle.net/Ax8Hz/23/

Comment: i did not add the library in this code above but in the fiddle, it is loaded and it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how to pass a reference of current object (an anchor) to your function. The correct way is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="popup(this)">Open</a>
```

So, my solution is:

```js
function popup(obj)
{
  var myHtml = '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Popup</title></head><body>' +
      $(obj).next('.CodeBlock').html() +
      '</body></html>';

  var generator = window.open('','name','height=400,width=500');
  generator.document.body.innerHTML = myHtml;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" onclick="popup(this)">Open</a>
<div class="CodeBlock">
    line 1<br />
    line 2<br />
    line 3
</div>
<br /><br />
<a href="#" onclick="popup(this)">Open</a>
<div class="CodeBlock">
    line 4<br />
    line 5<br />
    line 6
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! That is what i was looking for. The first method with (0) and (1) also works fine, but the anchor is dynamically generated as part of a php string, so i was looking for a way without (0), (1), (2) etc.... this really works great! Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

How about iterating through the elements like this (using jquery):

```
function popup()
{
  var generator=window.open('','name','height=400,width=500');

  generator.document.write('<html><head><title>Popup</title>');
  $(".CodeBlock").each(function (index, element) {
    generator.document.write($(element).html());
  });
  generator.document.write('</body></html>');
  generator.document.close();
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, this will show the content of all divs. Using jquery it is possible to get the value of the next div, for at given anchor (a) like this (using an alert to show it):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).click(function(event) {
              alert($(element).next('div').html());
      });
    });
  });
```

This also makes the popup function in the anchor superfluous.

Comment: i tried this in a new fiddle but unfortunately, this also is not the solution http://jsfiddle.net/Ax8Hz/25/

Comment: I just updated the code - added $() around the element, please try again.

Comment: It also works with element.innerHTML instead of $(element).html(), if you want to avoid wrapping the element in a jquery object. http://jsfiddle.net/Ax8Hz/26/

Comment: Well, the first and the second popup contain line 1 till Line 6. the first popup must contain Line 1 till Line 3 and the second must contain Line 4 till Line 6

Comment: Each anchor must popup the content of the class"CodeBlock" below of it

Comment: Arh - I had not noticed that. I made an edit using jquery (I just had to try it :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

Pass your current `control` through the function as parameter and then use `.next` to fetch its `next` element. You aren't doing it right way. You must see some **console error** saying *`$.next` is not a function*

```
<a href="javascript:popup(this);">Open</a> <!--Pass "this" here-->
<div class="CodeBlock">
   line 1<br />
   line 2<br />
   line 3
</div>
<br /><br />
<a href="javascript:popup(this);">Open</a>
<div class="CodeBlock">
   line 4<br />
   line 5<br />
   line 6
</div>
```

**JS** update:

```
function popup(ctrl)
{
  var generator=window.open('','name','height=400,width=500');

  generator.document.write('<html><head><title>Popup</title>');
  generator.document.write($(ctrl).next(".CodeBlock").html());
  //use $(ctrl).next
  generator.document.write('</body></html>');
  generator.document.close();
}
```

Comment: i tried this code above, but both popups give me the content: **undefined**